# Can someone Identify why I am getting index out of range?

Tags: swift

I am trying to read data from a file and store them in two dimenationa Array.

I am facing an error " tempArr[x] = number! " which is index out of range.

I am not able to find the cause of the problem.

```swift
    func loadData(){

        let path = "/Users/ushehri/Desktop/imageData/imageData/imageData/imageData.txt"

        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: path){

            do {
                var x = 0

                let fullData = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                let readings = fullData.components(separatedBy: ",") as [String]
                var tempArr = [Double]()
                for i in 0..<readings.count {

                    let number = Double(readings[i])

                        tempArr[x] = number!
                        x = x + 1
                        if( x == 8){
                            x = 0
                        imageNumber.append(tempArr)
                        tempArr.removeAll()
                    }


                }

                for z in 0...readings.count{
                    for r in 0...8 {
                        print(imageNumber[z][r])
                    }
                }



            } catch let error as NSError{
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just eyeballing, but `for z in 0...readings.count` jumps out. Try changing it to `for z in 0..<readings.count `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate your array like this:

`var tempArr = [Double]()`

This is just creating an array, but no storage is being allocated. If you attempt to access the array using an element index, you are attempting to access unallocated memory.

If you must preallocate the array, you can do it like this:

`let tmpArray = [Double](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0.0)`

It better to just use the append method of Array to add your elements.

There are some other issues with your code you may wish to address.  You are blindly assuming number will be valid:

`let number = Double(readings[i])`

Consider using either `if let number` or `guard let number` and handle the invalid data properly.

You should also consider assigning `8` to a constant, as you are using this magic number several times in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what if I can't pre-determine the array size?

Comment: You can just call tmpArray.append(number). In general, you don't need to preallocate arrays.